# Namespaces to identify change in XML data?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

Let's say the data in XML file named "1jan2018.xml":

```
"1jan2018.xml"
<instrument id="12345" xmlns="12345">
    <type>guitar</guitar>
    <maker>Fender</maker>
    <model>Stratocaster 1979</model>
    <condition>used</condition>
    <price>4500</price>
</instrument>
<instrument id="12225" xmlns="12225">
    <type>guitar</guitar>
    <maker>Ibanez</maker>
    <model>JS Signature 100S</model>
    <condition>New</condition>
    <price>3400</price>
</instrument>
```

The next day, in file named "2jan2018.xml" the prices change:

```
"2jan2018.xml"
<instrument id="12345" xmlns="12345">
    <type>guitar</guitar>
    <maker>Fender</maker>
    <model>Stratocaster 1979</model>
    <condition>used</condition>
    <price>4400</price>
</instrument>
<instrument id="12225" xmlns="12225">
    <type>guitar</guitar>
    <maker>Ibanez</maker>
    <model>JS Signature 100S</model>
    <condition>New</condition>
    <price>3200</price>
</instrument>
```

**Reason for default namespaces**: To avoid adding prefixes to each of the child elements.
**Assumption**: Adding namespaces same as the instrument/@id will enable tracking of every child element's change in data/value. Let's say there is a system that takes care of adding the default namespaces to the raw file.
**Aim 1**: To find a way to track changes in child nodes. 
**Aim 2**: generate only "changed data" in the xml file generated the next day. I'm thinking XSLT can be used for this aim (I'm thinking out aloud - not an expert here).
e.g.
In "2jan2018.xml" file, the data should be simply

```
<instrument id="12345" xmlns="12345">
    <price>4400</price>
</instrument>
<instrument id="12225" xmlns="12225">
    <price>3200</price>
</instrument>
```

**Questions**:

- Is using default namespaces a good idea for tracking purpose? (Aim 1). If not, what is the best way to track change in data in the XML universe?
- I know this should be separate question in itself, but is XSLT viable to satisfy aim 2 or should I be looking in a completely different direction? Atleast if I can get the direction for this one..

Comment: Using namespaces for change tracking is an *absolutely terrible* idea. Don't do that. *"What is the best way to track change in data in the XML universe?"* - There is no universal solution when you want a particular effect. There are various `xmldiff` tools that you can investigate for their usefulness. If none does what you want, a bespoke solution (XSLT or otherwise) would be an option.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I will take a look at the xmldiff tools. Cheers to learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really bad idea. It's not what namespaces were designed for, and it will get you into all kinds of little practical difficulties. For example, using XPath to find elements across multiple namespaces gets really cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you have any suggestion on what I can look into as a potential solution for Aim#1?

Comment: There's a vast literature on change tracking in XML, but I'm no expert. If you google for "change tracking in XML" you will soon know more than I do.